# Why does a spinning top with mass farther away from the center spins for more time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, friction

Consider that I have two exact spinning tops (same format, same height, same tip), but one has most of its mass distributed on the **outside** part of it (**spinning top 1**), and the other one has the same mass distributed in the **inside** part of it (**spinning top 2**).

I spin the two tops as hard as I can and observe that the one with the mass on the outside spins longer.

One possible explanation is that the spinner with the mass on the outside has more energy, and thus will spin for a longer tim. Thinking about kinetic energy (E = mv²/2, where v is the linear velocity of a point in the spinner), the spinner with the mass on the outside will have more energy, given each mass point will have more linear velocity.

However, my question is: if I spin the tops with my hands (trying to spin both as hard as I can), will I give more energy to the spinning top 1 (mass on the outside), without noticing it? That's why it spins for a longer time? Or will I give the same energy to both, and the one with the mass on the outside will have less velocity? In that case, why does it spin for a longer time?

I'm doing some experiments with spinners for kids and would like to explain what is going on in an intuitive way, without formulas and definitions that most people don't understand.

Comment: Remember that without friction, both would in principle spin forever, no matter how much or little energy you give them. What makes them stop? I would guess that they either stop because they dissipate the energy, or because the tumble over and fall down. Why could this happen in different ways for different mass distributions?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing some experiments with spinners for kids and would like to explain what is going on intuitively, without formulas and definitions that most people don't understand.

One way you could explain this to kids is by using the concept of inertia. They might be familiar with the idea that a heavy body in motion has more inertia, and is difficult to bring to a halt, whereas a lighter body has less inertia, and is easier to change its state of rest or uniform motion.

Now you may explain that there is a similar kind of inertia for rotating bodies, defined as Moment of inertia. The spinning tops with mass distributed far from their spinning axis have a high moment of inertia and are more difficult to bring to a complete halt.

> However, my question is: if I spin the tops with my hands (trying to spin both as hard as I can), will I give more energy to the spinning top 1 (mass on the outside), without noticing it? That's why it spins for a longer time? Or will I give the same energy to both, and the one with the mass on the outside will have less velocity? In that case, why does it spin for a longer time?

Inertia is an intrinsic property of a body, and its mass is a way of quantifying it. Newton's second law states that $F=ma$. For a given amount of force $F$, if the object accelerates/decelerates quickly, it means the mass $m=F/a$ is low, and hence inertia is low (Think of a car towing a bike). For the same force, if another object accelerates/decelerates slowly, that object has high mass and hence high inertia (Think of a car towing a truck).

Similarly in the case of spinning tops, for the same torque you apply, if the top has a low angular acceleration/deceleration, it has a high moment of inertia. If it accelerates/decelerates fast, it has a low moment of inertia. In your case, the top spinning for a longer time means that for the same friction torque, it decelerates lesser, meaning its moment of inertia is high. You could then go on and introduce the formula for the moment of inertia, to be $I=\sum_i^N m_i r_i^2$, which is in line with our idea that the fatter spinning top should have more $I$ than the thinner one.

[image]

**Note to the informed readers:**

This answer is not a comprehensive one in any manner, but may be useful for the general audience. Also kindly excuse my misuse of physical terms along with linguistic ones.